# Error while calling AddLine function of Autocad API

Tags: vbscript, qtp, autocad

I am working on API programming for `Autocad 2013` in UFT as follows:

```
Public Function Test() 
    Dim oApp, oDoc , sptr(2) , eptr(2) , objLine 
    Set oApp = GetObject(,"Autocad.Application")
     Set oDoc = oApp.ActiveDocument 
    sptr(0) = 1 : sptr(1) = 1 : sptr(2) = 0 
    eptr(0) = 5 : eptr(1) = 5 :eptr(2) = 0 
    Set objLine = oDoc.ModelSpace.AddLine(sptr,eptr) 
    oApp.Visible = True 
  End Function 

   Call Test()
```

I'm getting the following error at `Set objLine`:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

As it is VBScript, is this correct way to pass the start and end points?

Comment: Maybe `sptr(0) = CDbl(1) : sptr(1) = CDbl(1) : sptr(2) = CDbl(0)` etc. could help?

Comment: No. I have checked for CDbl but still getting same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddLine()` function expects an array of `Double` values. VBScript can only create arrays of `Variant` values. Fortunately, AutoCAD includes a function called `CreateTypedArray()` as part of its `Utility` class that allows you to create *typed* arrays that you can then pass to AutoCAD functions.

```
Dim s, e
oDoc.Utility.CreateTypedArray s, vbDouble, 1, 1, 0   ' Make 's' a Double array
oDoc.Utility.CreateTypedArray e, vbDouble, 5, 5, 0   ' Make 'e' a Double array
Set objLine = oDoc.ModelSpace.AddLine(s, e)          ' Pass our new arrays
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks... now its working with vbscript in uft.